# add subfolder to ignored lists while the parent folder specified as not ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following in my `.gitignore` file:

```
www/bower_components/*
!www/bower_components/bootstrap
```

Which is - ignore everything inside `www/bower_components` except for `bootstrap` folder.
Now I want the `dist` folder inside `bootstrap` to be ignored. How do I do that? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
www/bower_components/*
!www/bower_components/bootstrap
www/bower_components/bootstrap/dist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a `.gitignore` file in the `bootstrap` directory ignoring `dist`.

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the
>   path, or in any parent directory, **with patterns in the higher level
>   files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those
>   in lower level files** down to the directory containing the file.

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but then they still were tracked. And it just occurred to me that I needed to remove them from being tracked. Best!